# Extending the faktor package

Tags: math-mode, package-writing

I'm writing a script (topic ring theory) where I have to set lots of quotients of algebraic objects. Usually I simply write `M/N`. However there are some cases where this is no easy to read (`M+N/N` or such). So I want to set the first object a bit higher and the second a bit lower. I found the [faktor](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/faktor) package which does this. However faktor uses `\diagup` in a fixed size. For larger expressions a larger one seems suitable. Do you have any idea how I can change the source code of the package so that

1. I have two commands (one with a small and one with a large slash) or better
2. the `\diagup` has automatically the right size.

I also tried `xfrac`. First I ran into this message:

```
This is a LaTeX bug: check coding!
! Command name `\if_num:w' already defined! Current meaning: \ifnum.
\msg_kernel_bug:x ...oding!}\tex_errmessage:D {#1}
```

A [comment at Debians bug tracking system](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=568321#10) suggested to exchange `mathtools` and `xfrac`. This worked on my system. However the formulas inside a `gather*`-environment look too small to me:
[image: example with \sfrac]

The font size here seems smaller than at inline text. Thatswhy I wanted to try `faktor`.

I noticed another disadvantage with `xfrac`. My document needs *a lot more* time to compile. The initial revision took ~13 sec to compile (pdflatex) and with `xfrac` it took ~1300 secs or nearly half an hour.

Comment: Rather than [`faktor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/faktor), have you had a look at the [`xfrac` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac)?

Comment: I upgraded my question with an explanation of my `xfrac` experiments.

Comment: I can't see how using `xfrac` could increase your compile time 100 fold. This should not be the case.

Comment: You were right. `xfrac` was not the problem. I played around a bit and found out that `microtype` is the problem. If `microtype` and `xfrac` are used together I get an enormous increase in compile time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In essence, the [`faktor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/faktor) defines the command `\faktor` in the following way (let's call it `\newfaktor`):

```
\newcommand*{\newfaktor}[2]{% \newfaktor{#1}{#2} -> #1/#2
  \raisebox{0.5\height}{\ensuremath{#1}}% Numerator
  \mkern-5mu\diagup\mkern-4mu% Slash /
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\ensuremath{#2}}% Denominator
}
```

Here is the similarity between `\faktor` and `\newfaktor`:

[image: \faktor vs \newfaktor]

In order to satisfy the first request - to modifying the height/depth to which the numerator/denominator is raised/dropped - you could define some extra optional parameters for `\newfaktor`. And, for the sake of being complete, the [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides a convenient way of intermixing mandatory `{}` and optional `[]` arguments:

```
\usepackage{xparse}%
...
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newfaktor}{m O{0.5} m O{-0.5}}{% \newfaktor{#1}[#2]{#3}[#4] -> #1/#3
  \raisebox{#2\height}{\ensuremath{#1}}% Numerator
  \mkern-5mu\diagup\mkern-4mu% Slash /
  \raisebox{#4\height}{\ensuremath{#3}}% Denominator
}
```

This defines the command `\newfaktor{#1}[#2]{#3}[#4]` where `#2` and `#4` have defaults of `0.5` and `-0.5` respectively, and are optional. These optional arguments specify the fractional height/depth to which the numerator `#1` and denominator `#3` are raised/dropped. That is, specifying `0.5` for `#2` *raises* `#1` by half of its regular height; specifying `-1` for `#4` *drops* `#3` by its own height. For example:

[image: Different new faktor styles]

In the above image, the first four uses of `\newfaktor` yield a typesetting equivalent to `\faktor`.

In order to satisfy the second request - `\diagup` scales automatically with respect to its arguments - we have to go a different route. The reason for this is that scaling `\diagup` happens in 2 dimensions, thereby making `\diagup` fatter. See, for example, the difference between:

[image: Scaling of \diagup]

So, instead, I went with stretching a `\rule`, built into the following macro:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newfaktor}{s m O{0.5} m O{-0.5}}{% \newfaktor[*]{#2}[#3]{#4}[#5] -> #2/#4
  \setbox0=\hbox{\ensuremath{#2}}% Store numerator
  \setbox1=\hbox{\ensuremath{\diagup}}% Store slash /
  \setbox2=\hbox{\ensuremath{#4}}% Store denominator
  \raisebox{#3\ht1}{\usebox0}% Numerator
  \mkern-5mu\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\BooleanTrue}}% Slash /
    {\diagup}% regular \faktor slash
    {\rotatebox{-44}{\rule[#5\ht2]{0.4pt}{-#5\ht2+#3\ht0+\ht0}}}% tilted rule as a slash
  \mkern-4mu%
  \raisebox{#5\ht2}{\usebox2}% Denominator
}
```

This creates `\newfaktor` just like before, but now with an optional `*`. The starred version `\newfaktor*` reverts to the older definition, using `\diagup` as the slanted fraction, while the unstarred `\newfaktor` draws a `\rule` and tilts it into place. Consider the differences:

[image: Modified \newfaktor with sizable slash]

[image: Longer equations using starred/unstarred \newfaktor]

Of course, if these definitions are entirely satisfaktory(!), you can change them to your liking.