# Disable microtype for a portion of a document

Tags: microtype

### Update: 2013-04-18

After upgrading to `microtype` 2.5 today this specific test cases indeed runs much faster (from approximately 3:00 minutes down to 8 seconds).  However, I do have another cases where the compile time has not quite improved as much: only went down from 2:05 hr to 1:30 hr.

### Question:

I would like to disable the features of the `microtype` package for a portion of the document. I attempted to use `\microtypesetup{activate=false}` but that seems to have no effect.  Additional options I tried included:

```
\microtypesetup{expansion=false}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\microtypesetup{kerning=false}
\microtypesetup{tracking=false}
```

and did not seem to fix the compile time issue.

### Background:

This problem seems related to [Why does the use of microtype and xfrac lead to a long compile time?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27963/why-does-the-use-of-microtype-and-xfrac-lead-to-a-high-compile-time) as my compile time for this small document is very large if **all** three of the `\def` defined at the top are uncommented: ie.,

- The `microtype` package is used, *and*
- `\sfrac` from the `xfrac` pacakge is used, *and*
- My "extended" version of the `\bracr` macro is used

Otherwise this document compiles just fine.  With `%\def\UseMicrotype{}` commented, and the other two `\def` uncommented, this produces:

[image]

The last sentence is only to show why I need the "extended" version of the `\bracr` macro.

### Notes:

- I am using `microtype` from CTAN (2.4), and will update to 2.5 once it is released (which apparently does not have this long compile time issue with `\sfrac`).  In the mean time, if there is a way to disable `microtype` that would be helpful.

### Code:

```
%%% Problems ONLY if ALL three of these are uncommented
%\def\UseMicrotype{}%    Enable use of microtype.
\def\UseExtendedBrac{}% Enable use of "extended" version of \brac macro
\def\UseSFrac{}%        Enable use of \sfrac

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{xfrac}%     Provides sfrac


\ifdefined\UseMicrotype
    \usepackage{microtype}%  
\fi


\ifdefined\UseExtendedBrac% 
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\@Brac}[3]{% #1,#3 = left/right bracket type
        \ensuremath{%
            \left#1\vphantom{#2}\right.% left bracket
            #2% content
            \left.\vphantom{#2}\right#3% right bracket
        }%
    }%
    \newcommand{\bracr}[1]{\@Brac{(}{#1}{)}}%
    \newcommand{\bracs}[1]{\@Brac{[}{#1}{]}}%
    \makeatother
\else% Works if these are used
    \newcommand{\bracr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
    \newcommand{\bracs}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\fi

\ifdefined\UseSFrac
\else% No problem if we don't use \sfrac
    \renewcommand*{\sfrac}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}%
\fi

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\UseMicrotype
    \microtypesetup{activate=false}
\fi
%
\begin{align*}
    f(x,y)
    &= \bracr{\frac{x^{ \sfrac{3}{2}}}
                    y^{-\sfrac{1}{2}}}^{\!\!\!-2} \\
    &= \bracr{ 
        \bracs{
            \frac{x^{ \sfrac{3}{2}}}
                 {y^{-\sfrac{1}{2}}}}^2}^{\!\!\!-1}
\end{align*}
%
% Reason for using the "extended" brac as it yields line wrapping.
As we can see in the following, the \verb|\bracr| wraps around lines: 
$\bracr{x^{-1} + x^{-2} + x^{-3} +x^{-4} + x^{-5} + \cdots }$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure is `microtype` or the fact that xfrac loads the LaTeX3 packages?

Comment: Its the interaction between `microtype` and `xfrac`. My "extended" `bracr` macro just makes things much worse. If you don't use `microtype` things work just fine (this is how the code as posted is: disables `microtype`, uses `\sfrac`).

Comment: Just a note: nicefrac causes the same problems as xfrac

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just in case you're still using the rather old, yet still official version 2.4: the undocumented key `disable` will *really* turn off microtype, `enable` will, well, enable it again:

```
\microtypesetup{disable}
...
\microtypesetup{enable}
```

**EDIT:** Since `microtype` v3.0 these keys have been renamed to `deactivate` and `reactivate`, resepectively, but they remain undocumented as they are not meant for general use, but only as a last resort until a bug fix is available. So whenever you find yourself being forced to use these keys, make sure to also file a [bug report](https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/issues).

Comment: +1 As, this certainly helps, but not sure that it totally turns off `microtype`. Without your solution, and with `%\def\UseMicrotype{}` commented, this takes approx 3 seconds to run. With `micortype` enabled it takes about 3 minutes to run, which is an increase in the run time of a factor of 60x.  With the addition of `\microtypesetup{disable}` before `\begin{align*}`, and `\microtypesetup{enable}` before `\end{document}`, the run time drops to 30 seconds. So, it is _still_ takes about 10 times longer to run.

Comment: It does totally turn off microtype for that part of the document. The delay you experience then happens at `\begin{document}` resp. `\end{document}`. Just for the record: with microtype 2.5 it would take about 7 seconds with microtype enabled throughout (on my computer, I get similar times as you do)