# Is there a trick to beautify bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, memoir, typography

I'm using the `memoir` and `biblatex` packages together. In general, I'm very happy with both. However, in my bibliography, I get some overflows and I don't have any clue how to avoid them... are there packages / commands / settings / tricks to achieve a nice looking bibliography and avoid overflows as depicted below? I know that latex does its best about type setting, but maybe there are some pitfalls I'm not aware of. Thank you!

[image][image]

**UPDATE**
Using the `block=ragged` option avoids overflows, but also omits the text justification I like so much :-) (see next figure) So unfortunately, this is not an alternative.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps put `DOI` and `ISBN` numbers on a line of their own?

Comment: Well, there are three (bad) options: go `\sloppy`, go `\raggedright` or allow linebreaks inside DOI.

Comment: the `biblatex` option `block=ragged` doesn't look too bad IMHO

Comment: @tohecz - What's so bad about allowing a line break in the DOI string?

Comment: @Mico Nothing technically, but the guideline mentioned in the `url` package docs should be followed: no breaking at `-` and no breaking inside alphanumerical sequences. This need not be enough.

Comment: btw, did I mention `\usepackage{microtype}` ? It's a must-have in these borderline cases.

Comment: @tohecz thank you, I will have a look at this package. It seems to be very powerful, but not "obvious" to use :-)

Comment: @strauberry You don't need to do anything, just load `microtype` after all font packages.

Comment: @tohecz Great, thank you! Now it looks much better! Do I have to thoroughly check my entire document (about 280 pages) or does microtype touch only the bibliography per default?

Comment: Microtype affects the whole document by default (usually for the better).

Comment: You can also try `\begingroup
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{4em}
  \printbibliography
\endgroup`. Credits to egreg (I think!).

Comment: This is perhaps not directly relevant but...even though `\raggedright` doesn't look quite as nice, paradoxically, it is much easier to read.

Comment: Re »`block=ragged` option avoids overflows, but also omits the text justification« – Well, of course! If the block is ragged it isn't justified. Those two contradict each other!

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments, [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) is your friend here, and produces nicer output for the rest of the document as well.

Because all of these options depend on your reference list/reference style/margin settings/font choices (which we do not have), I've listed a few options and compared them using a sample text (`\lipsum`) and sample reference list `biblatex-examples.bib` which should be included on any system with `biblatex` installed.

In addition to `microtype`, I'd recommend a setting for `biblatex`'s `block=` option. cgnieder suggested `block=ragged`, but I think this will be not acceptable for you given the update to your question. I've included it for future visitors, though. :-)

I think `block=space` would look closer to your ideal output. It allows extra space to be inserted between "blocks" in the bibliography, which can alleviate would-be line-breaking problems.

Another option could be `\RaggedRight` from [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e), which enables hyphenation without full justification, but this didn't look the greatest either considering your dissatisfaction with the `block=ragged` option. But again, this is highly dependent on the text/font/margins, so I've included it as an option for future visitors to try.

## MWE

Here's the base test MWE I used to compare the settings:

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir} % `draft' to show overfull \hboxes
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % `final' to prevent disabling
\usepackage[
  backend=biber, % default, but avoids warnings
  block=space,   % allow additional horizontal space between blocks
%  block=ragged,  % set the bibliography ragged right and introduce a line break penalty
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} % bunch of sample entries

\begin{document}
\lipsum    % print the sample text
\nocite{*} % print all references in the bibliography

%\raggedright
%\Raggedright
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Spoiler alert: the "best" (IMHO and for my test input/references) combination is shown in the sample above.

## Comparison

I've left out anything that's "too ragged" (except for the default result) based on your update above. From "worst" to "best":

- Default configuration; no `\raggedright`, no `\RaggedRight`, no `microtype`, default `block=none`: 14 bad boxes, worst `26.46pt` too wide
  [image]
- Add `microtype` with default settings: 4 bad boxes, worst `8.09pt` too wide
- Add `block=space` in addition to `microtype`: 1 bad box, `1.12pt` too wide
  [image]

I've shown the worst offender in the screenshots, but line breaks around long DOI/URL-like strings were also vastly improved. Two examples:

Before:
[image]
[image]
After:
[image]
[image]

## Notes

If for some reason you really want `microtype` enabled only in the bibliography (though I'd recommend to just use it throughout the document), you can use `\microtypesetup{disable}` and `\microtypesetup{enable}` at the appropriate places in your document, as detailed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75635/21344). These keys are still undocumented, but you can find the code in lines 4118–4128 of the current (v2.5a) package code (p. 125 of the v2.5a documentation).

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say I »recommend« `block=ragged`. »suggest« is maybe a better word... A ragged bibliography avoids nearly all bad boxes and the bibliography is much more readable than with justification. (But that's only my personal opinion :)

Comment: Fair enough @cgnieder; I'll update my word choice. :-)

Comment: `block=space` does the trick for me, thanks!