# Is microtype-2.5 (beta-08) stable enough for production use?

Tags: microtype

I am affected by the [performance issues of microtype-2.4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27963/11605) and enter the last phase of an important work (fine-tuning of page breaks, overfull hboxes, etc.). The compile time with microtype is about 4 minutes, with microtype in draft mode 30 seconds... A faster compile time would, therefore, vastly speed up the process of tuning. What is your experience with microtype-2.5 (beta-08) with pdflatex? Is it stable enough for production use?

Comment: I've been using 2.5 for a while because of XeTeX support, it seems to work fine.

Comment: I just tried 2.5 and get `Package microtype Warning: Loading generic settings for font family \`MinionPro-OsF'`, although a style should have been defined by [this](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/blob/master/tex/MinionPro.dtx#L1434) (I checked that the corresponding configuration file is loaded) with a fairly minimal document. With 2.4, this warning/error is not present. I'll prepare a bug report.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`microtype` version 2.5 (stable) has been issued on March 13, 2013. The confusing warning mentioned in the comments of the question has been addressed.