using faktor package in a Lyx document
I'm trying to use the faktor package in LyX for the quotient operator. However, LyX doesn't recognize the \faktor command, even though I've installed the package using Tex Live.
I'm fairly new to LyX and LaTeX, so I might be doing something wrong here. Here's what I've done:

I downloaded the package using Tex Live Shell.
Restarted Lyx.
In my document, I went to Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble and added \usepackage{faktor}.

Now when im trying to use \faktor in the math environment Lyx doesn't recognize the command so I'm left with a red colored \faktor sign that doesn't do anything.
after consulting with chatgpt on the matter he suggested that I go to Document -> Settings  -> Document Class there he said to write \usepackage{faktor} under Class Options -> Custom and that should get the job done. Unfortunately it didnt change anything.
Here's some additional information i thought might help one solve this issue:

This document is written as an Article (Standard Class with Extra Font Sizes).
The document Im working on is mainly written in Hebrew, but contains some English as well.
This document is a math course summery so roughly half of it is math.
I'm using Lyx2.3

Any sort of help would be very much appreciated, Thanks.
If anyone is aware of any alternative way (whether in a package or any other way) of using a quotient operator similar to the one in the  faktor package, please don't hesitate to replay. That would be very helpful as well.


Welcome to tex.sx.  Please add a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem.  That way potential helpers won't have to guess when they try to solve the problem.

Welcome. // You can open .lyx files with any ASCII-editor AND post that code here below your screenshot, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707511/245790 .  You could do the same with the Latex-windows content ... Thank you // How good do you know Latex?

BTW, do you know the package documentation: https://ctan.org/pkg/faktor ?

BTW, if I try package faktor in Latex (pdflatex), it doesn't compile ... hm, it's from 2006 ... // Here's a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27735/245790

Thanks for the help, but as i mentioned in the post itself I'm new to LaTeX so I really don't understand much of these posts. As far as the file you asked me to attach, I don't really see the point in that since the "problem" is just that the command is not working.  If you want me to attach a file that "shows" the problem, it will be a 1 line file therefor seems pointless to me. Again Thanks for the help

@MS-SPO  I'm new to LaTeX so if you have any simpler or clearer solutions is would be great :) as this post   tex.stackexchange.com/a/27735/245790    is complete gibberish to me. Thanks again

It's like this: If you know Latex, using Lyx is fine, while the opposite does not hold. I suggest to get some basic knowledge about Latex first, e.g. from books like this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX . Unfortunately Lyx is no replacement for Latex knowledge. // So, as we start running into a discussion I have to end my comments. Bye

LyX use a GUI to help you only the most common LaTeX and show how it could look (more or less) in the PDF, before of compiling, but is NOT able to interpret and represent any other LaTeX code, and there a lot out there. For these cases, ther is  Ctrl+L to insert TeX code, that in math in mode in just to type a command (start with a slash automatically) and in text mode is to make an  Evil Red TeX (ERT) box.  In both case just show raw LaTeX code as you see, and you can only check if that code is correct in the PDF preview, not in the orange screen.

@Fran, LyX has some utility to extend its GUI functionality to custom environment, commands, and math macros, they are limited in their own ways, and need some learning curve to understand how to use them, but it is sometimes nicer than ERT if you are going to use a command several times.

@UdiFogiel  I know that there are help for customization, but always I saw scarcely justified  get into those kind of troubles when an ERT can fix anything just knowing LaTeX. However, probably I am very biased  in this topic  because I switched from LyX to raw LaTEX editors long time ago.

LyX has the functionality to add new math macros that it will recognize in equations (it has its limitations, but for most cases it works quite OK). It is described in section 20.2 on the manual in Help->Math.
In your case here are the steps I would take:

Load the faktor package by adding the line \usepackage{faktor} in Document->Settings->LaTeX Preamble.

Load the amssymb package (which faktor requires without loading it itself) by selecting always in Document->Settings->Math Options->amssymb.

Insert a Math Macro inset by Insert->Math->Macroor by clicking on the button that has an image with \foo on it the the toolbar.

choose an unused name (not faktor for example) for the macro name (I will choose foo, but you should probably choose a name that will suit you) and type it in the macro name

In the TeX filed of the inset type \faktor + \{ then inside the box in the curly brackets type \# + 1, and again for a second argument but with 2 instead of 1.

In the LyX field type \nicefrac, then in the top box type \# + 1 and in the bottom box \# + 2.


Note that in LyX 2.4 that is about to come soon you could use the name faktor as name of the macro, and leave the TeX feild empty
After these steps when you will type \foo and a space in an equation you should see the following:

Here is an example file
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{faktor}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 2
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset FormulaMacro
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{\faktor{#1}{#2}}
{\nicefrac{#1}{#2}}
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\foo ab
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document


wow firstly thank you for going through all this. I'm aware of the nicefrac command its just that it makes everything you put in smaller. Unfortunately for me most of the times i have pretty long expressions in each of the slots. so eventually the font get so small its barely readable. again thank you for the help!!!

@userא0 I used nicefrac only as description to how lyx sould display the macro in the gui, it has nothing to do with the actual output in the PDF, nor to the latex output. Did you try using this method? Did you read the section in the manual I mentioned?

@userא0 you asked how to use the faktor macro in a math inset, and that LyX will "recognize" it, the other answer doesn't really solve that...

@UdiFogiel, you are right, and the main reason was this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/716204/using-faktor-package-in-a-lyx-document/716450?noredirect=1#comment1780200_716204 ;-)

@MS-SPO, See the second step I described, it is only a guess, but did you load amssymb? unfortunately faktor requires it without actually loading it itself.

@UdiFogiel, thanks for pointing that out. In fact, the manual says it needs amssymb, which I missed somehow. +1

@UdiFogiel I misunderstood you. your method indeed resolves my problem.

Did you follow the suggestion to learn and compile some LaTeX outside LyX? Makes things much easier for you ...
Here's one way to do it.
Developing with Latex
This is how it looks like in Latex. Key points:

trying the standard \frac{}{} : not nice
following raisebox approach, with some simplications
putting it into a \newcommand and trying it
so \newcommand\faktor[2]{\raisebox{5pt}{#1} / \raisebox{-5pt}{#2}} seems to do the job (good enough for now)


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% ~~~ mimicking: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27735/245790
\newcommand\faktor[2]{\raisebox{5pt}{#1} / \raisebox{-5pt}{#2}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{lll}
    for reference   & $\frac{\Re}{m_1 \Re}$ & math mode\\
    \textit{(empty line)}\\
    trying raisboxes& X\ \raisebox{5pt}{$\Re$} / \raisebox{-5pt}{$m_1 \Re$} & X for reference of baselines\\
    moving it into a newcommand& X\ \faktor{$\Re$}{$m_1 \Re$} & see preambel\\
    trying math mode&$A = \faktor{$\Re$}{$m_1 \Re$}$ & at least this works\\
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}

Using it with Lyx
Get ready for clicking.
To copy this \newcommand into the preamble use Documents/Settings:

Enter into the RED BOX (pain? horror? nope: non-Gui-ed Latex code ...)
$A = \faktor{$\Re$}{$m_1 \Re$}$


Final Lyx file (unfortunately my installation can't run it, so ...) *** copy, save and load into Lyx:
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\newcommand\faktor[2]{\raisebox{5pt}{#1} / \raisebox{-5pt}{#2}}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

$A = 
\backslash
faktor{$
\backslash
Re$}{$m_1 
\backslash
Re$}$
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document



Works like a charm!!!. Thank you so much
